# Checkbox border color styling in Angular material (md-checkbox)

Tags: css, html, checkbox, angular-material

I am just wondering if there is any way to style md-checkbox 
like given below:

[Codepen code for input checkbox](http://codepen.io/snehav27/pen/gpXgJv)

Note: I just wanna change the border color of the checkbox.

I have tried following way but didn't succeed :

SCSS

```
$dal-green: #45ba8e;
    .check{
    md-checkbox {
      border: 2px solid $dal-green; 
    }
    }
```

HTML :

```
     <div class="check"> 
<md-checkbox></md-checkbox>
</div>
```

I have searched online but no luck . If any body can give css to override the border color it would be great help. Thanks In advance.

Comment: it seems `<md-checkbox>` creates `<div class='md-icon' />` which defaults to an unchecked box area. Try applying css to this `.md-icon` I learnt it from here, github.com/angular/material/issues/2832 (the last comment)

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
.check{
md-checkbox {
  border: 2px solid #009688; 
}
}
```

Comment: Its not working color is not a problem here assigning color to the border of the  checkbox.

Comment: it seems `<md-checkbox>` creates `<div class='md-icon' />` which defaults to an unchecked box area. Try applying css to this `.md-icon` I learnt it from here, https://github.com/angular/material/issues/2832 (the last comment)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
md-checkbox .md-icon {
  border-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in new version you should use with underscore _md-icon:

```
        md-checkbox.md-checked ._md-icon {
         background-color: transparent;
        }


        md-checkbox ._md-icon {
        border-color: white;
        }
```